# Flyway DataBase initialization or update

Tags: flyway

I want to use flyway for an existing application.

There should be two different cases:

1) Application installation: DDL and initilization of the Database

2) Application update: migrate database

The problem is if i install Version 6.0 i have e.g.:

> ```
> V1_0_1__CreateShema (for 6.0.0)
> V1_0_2__InitData (for 6.0.0)
> ....
> V4_0_0__Update_DDL_and_DML
> V5_0_0__Update_DDL_and_DML
> V6_0_0__Update_DDL_and_DML
> ```

If i set init version to V1.0.0 it will execute all updates until V6_0_0 but it should skip all updates after initialization of the Database.

To install an old shema so i can use all udpate scripts even for a fresh install would be very hard (no db version history so i have to do reverse engineering)

I could use a workaround:

> ```
> 1) Check if version table exist
> 2) If not - migrate to version 1.0.2
> 3) drop the version table
> 4) init again with version 6.0.0
> ```

There should be a better way isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

I've highlighted the problem:

V1_0_1__CreateShema **(for 6.0.0)**
V1_0_2__InitData **(for 6.0.0)**

To get to 6.0 you should run all scripts up to V6_0_0__Update_DDL_and_DML

V1 should be for V1 and never change afterwards.